# compare meta-data with cvs metadata

Tags: 2007, column-data

I have uploaded 100s of documents with metadata using Syntergy's bulkloader. Now, I need to compare the metadata from the csv file that bulkloader uses vs after load metadata from sharepoint.

I have a feeling there are or is some good links on this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Place all the metadata columns in a view and Export it to a datasheet or access, then do a side by side comparison of the data perhaps.

Comment: Eric, So you are suggesting importing all the metadata for an item into a dataview and then export it excel or access. Then do a compare outside. I was thinking put the metadata in stringbuilder, read meta data from csv file, then have the tool compare it and write delta to a log file.

Comment: Whatever floats your boat.  I'm not familiar with that tool and since you've already uploaded the files, the metadata should be in the list right?  Export it and compare the csv to that data.  I think there's a diff type function in Excel, so if the data is aligned and sorted in the same fashion, it might be pretty quick.

That's how I'd do it since it'd take me longer to script something like that up than to sit down and look at the differences.